# Bootstrap toggle collapse not working while trying to show more options in a html form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a html form with couple of input elements (displayed) and few input elements are collapsed with bootstrap with a "More Options" button to see the hidden elements which are optional in the form.

```
 <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#optional" class="btn btn-default">More Options</button>
```

When the page is first loaded and i click on the more options button it works perfect like how toggle collapse should work in bootstrap. But the issue is when i fill all the displayed elements and then click "More Options" button it's not working and flickering open and permanently closing. 
Unable to find what exactly causing it. Here is fiddle i tried.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulukil/qcofatc6/1/)

And how do i resolve it?

Comment: Did you try to add `type="button"` to your "More Options" `button` element ?

Comment: DavidDomain is correct ... if you don't specify the type="button" attribute it defaults to submit. See link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidDomain it's just a silly mistake i made and it caused such a trouble. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: @orangeh0g thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to an `a` tag. After filling the form, the scripts thinks you are actually validating your form instead of displaying more options.

Change this:

```
 <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#optional" class="btn btn-default">More Options</button>
```

To This:

```
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#optional" class="btn btn-default">More Options</a>
```

Comment: Yes this is a possible solution but is this a link that goes to another url or place on the page.  Not really.  This is however a button to do button type stuff.  Just add the button attribute type and set it to "button". Really I believe this is why the button tag was added to the HTML spec so anchor tags could be links and buttons could be buttons.

Comment: Having links inside a form is totally acceptable. If button doesn't work in his case, why even bother using it. And its not agains HTML spec.

Answer (score 1):

Adding attribute type in the button html element solved my issue. Thanks to @DavidDomain for explaining.

```
type="button"
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```